# How do I retrieve the lasttime a pipeline failed in Log analytics azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I need to retrieve the last run time a pipeline failed by using the below query but it doesn't work.

```
ADFPipelineRun 
| where Status == "Failed" AND  max(TimeGenerated)
```

So with the below example, I want to retrieve only the ones highlighted red on the screenshot. I have different pipelines and would like to retrieved only the last runtime of all the pipelines that failed.

[image]

For example in the above screenshot, I will like to retrieve only:
[image]

I need the Kusto query that can do that.

Comment: you should try to use something like `order by` in kusto.

Comment: Order by won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the query below. It returns the expected result as per my testing:

```
ADFPipelineRun 
| where Status == "Failed"
| summarize TimeGenerated= max(TimeGenerated) by PipelineName, Status
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer KQL Query, if you are working on azure synapse pipeline**

```
    SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns
    | where PipelineName == 'your_pipeline_name1'
    or PipelineName ==  'your_pipeline_name2'
        | where Status == 'Failed'
summarize TimeGenerated= max(TimeGenerated) by PipelineName, Status
```